# Cannot navigate to button (web scraping) - selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using selenium to do some web scraping, and I am having trouble getting the program to click on a certain button. Here is the specific error message:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

I am not sure what is wrong (I have tried these ways to try navigating to the button including:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("HTML-NAME").click()
driver.find_element_by_class("HTML-CLASS").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("HTML-ID").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='HTML-ID']").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("HTML-LINK-TEXT").click()
```

Here is the corresponding HTML code to the button I am trying to click:

```
< a name="HTML-NAME" id="HTML-ID" ptlinktgt="CODE"tabindex="30" onclick="javascript:cancelBubble(event);" href="javascript:submitAction....." class="HTML-CLASS">BTN-TEXT </a

# My code right now

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path/chromedriver")
url = "https://...."

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

input_bar1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='inp1']")
input1 = input("Username: ")
input_bar1.send_keys(username)

input_bar2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='inp2']")
input2 = input("Password: ")
input_bar2.send_keys(password)

input_bar2.submit()
time.sleep(5)

elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("BTN-TEXT")
elem.click()
time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: It looks like there's a trailing space that you're missing

Comment: Sorry I'm quite a beginner at this, what trailing space are you referring to?

Comment: "BTN-TEXT " (extra space at the end)

Comment: Did you checked if the link exist in the iframe?

Comment: is there a public url to share?

Comment: Just solved it! It was within an iframe so I had to switch the driver to iframe to find the element. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to increase the waiting time after the submit.
Probably the Browser has to load something (after the submitting) and you are trying to click the element before it is generated in the DOM. 
(TIPP: the number in wait(number) is the time in millis. So you are waiting 5 milliseconds before you try to click the BTN-TEXT element. Try increasing this number.